# How to defer non-critical CSS in next.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js

Recently I started exploring *Next.js* and found out that it provides built-in support for importing CSS using the `import` statement in the following manner.

```js
import '../styles.css'
```

Now, I wonder if it can somehow allow me to defer the non-critical CSS which is currently blocking the main thread. I can always use the [good old method of deferring CSS](https://web.dev/defer-non-critical-css/) as follows.

```html
<link rel="preload" href="styles.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

But my question remains, Is there a way to defer CSS when using the `import` statement?